# how to implement code for signal loss or site down?

Tags: iphone, ios4, reachability

In my app I am using webservices. I have implemented the Network Reachability using Reachability class. But that checks only when i start my application.

Note that, while downloading the data if loss of signal or site down occurs, I want to show the alert window.

Can this be done with the use of Reachability class? If yes than how to implement this? If no than what is the other way to implement ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this with help of `NSNotificationCenter`

```
- (void) addReachability
{
    //Use the Reachability class to determine if the internet can be reached.
        [[Reachability sharedReachability] setHostName:kHostName];

    //Set Reachability class to notifiy app when the network status changes.
    [[Reachability sharedReachability] setNetworkStatusNotificationsEnabled:YES];

    //Set a method to be called when a notification is sent.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) 
                                                 name:@"kNetworkReachabilityChangedNotification" object:nil];

}

- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)note 
{
    [AppDelegate updateStatus];
}
```

Comment: Do i need to add method - (BOOL)startNotifier ?

Comment: refer Reachability.m carefully you will get your answer

Comment: Actually i refered to it. But i did not get the idea what exactly -(BOOL)startNotifier does...

Comment: In this code provided by you, method is not being called when i switch off the WiFi. Is notification called only in device ?

Comment: i have tested this code in simulator too. when I unplugged LAN cable notification get fired...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. Once you register to get the status any change will hit the callback. Handle it accordingly.